# Why are there files named in binary in my root directory?

Tags: boot

Here's a picture of what I'm seeing:

[image: picture]

My computer is not booting; it was working, and I showed some work to someone, then I shut my PC off. When I went to turn it back on an hour later, it was not working. This is what I saw in my root directory. As far as I can tell, convering UTC time to local time, these were created as I was wrapping up my demo which would make less sense. It looks like the files were created 5 minutes apart.

Is this some sort of corruption? My SSD going bad? Something else entirely? Has anyone seen this issue before?

Edit: I was able to pull the file names. It was suggested to try translating them from Hebrew.

I used `listdir` in `python`, and it returned the following:

> ['opt', 'srv',
>   '\xcc\xaeO\x12G\xf0\xf6\xees\xaf\xa9\xf8\xda\x18\xb1\xbdo\xac',
>   'proc', 'snap', 'boot', 'lib64', 'usr', 'root', 'sys', 'etc', 'lib',
>   'sbin', 'mnt', 'home', 'vmlinuz', 'var', 'dev', 'cdrom', 'run',
>   'initrd.img', 'lost+found', 'initrd.img.old', 'bin', 'tmp',
>   'vmlinuz.old', 'media',
>   '\x08#\x94^M\xc92\x14\xb5\x06\xc2\xb6P\x02`\x88\xb6\x86rv{YX\xceyRNhc\xf4uh\x98\xa8\xce\x7f\x87\x112\x98\xe5W[\xfb39\xc6G\x9e\xb03\xb6fG\xce\x1a\xa6v\x8ar\xa3=G\xe7\r\xee*\xf04\x0e\xaa\x07\xc0\xda\x01\xd3\x1b\x01\xa6\xab\xbd@\x03\xa3k9}H\x0f,\x92A\xb0\xccoG\xe0\x872C\x85R\x81\xe7Q\xc4\xf4\x1f\x90\xdeV\x03\xefQ\x1b\x0e\xb9\xc8\xdf\x14\x0f\xd65\xbb\x17@\xf3\x14u\xa2\x1e#}D\xdc-a\xdd\x0f\xb0\x05\xec\xb6p.V\xec\xe0\xf0\xc9@\xe5\xd0E\x1c\xa0u7~+n\xc1\xf9\xed\xf7\x16\xb1M']

Comment: You have a corrupted system. It's best to re-install so that the issue doesn't worsen . Find out what the wear leveling count on your  SSD is.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi I'm having issues getting my files off my drive, it keeps telling me that certain files cannot be accessed :/ I was hoping a reinstall would not be necessary.

Comment: You can try to access them via a live CD or live USB as long as your HDD wasn't encrypted

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi Could this be from filling up the hard drive? I was generating test cases and accidentally filled my hard drive. Its possible that I haven't shut off the computer since then and only put it to sleep.

Comment: try this:  `convmv -r --notest -f windows-1255 -t UTF-8 *` in the terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49883/discussion-between-tatakai-wasumi-and-jfa).

Comment: It spat out 'To prevent damage to your files, we won't continue.
First fix this or correct options!'

Answer (score 0):

The file names were too long to rename, I wound up using:

```
ls -Ral ./ | grep -a '[^a-zA-Z0-9|[:punct:]| ]' | rm
```

as the super user. Didn't fix my boot, but at least those files are gone.